# How IIS/Owin converts IHttpActionResult to application/json down the pipeline?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, asp.net-web-api2, owin

I am exploring how IIS/Owin pipeline works. I am trying to find the library/method used by IIS/Owin down the pipeline to convert IHttpActionResult (returned from controller) into the correct content-type like application/json as present in the request.

Controller -

```
[Route("")]
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{
    IEnumerable<Product> productList = ProductService.GetAllProducts();
    if (!productList.Any())
        return Ok();

    return Json(productList, new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        ContractResolver = new WebContractResolver(),
        Converters = new List<JsonConverter> { new TrimStringDataConverter() }
    });
}
```

Data received by API consumer -

```
[
    {
        "code": "prod101",
        "title": "LAPTOP"
    },
    {
        "code": "prod102",
        "title": "MOBILE"
    }
]
```

When this conversion from IHttpActionResult to application/json takes place ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IHttpActionResult` has a method `ExecuteAsync` which returns `HttpResponseMessage`

```
public interface IHttpActionResult
{
    Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken);
}
```

When you use `Json()` in your controller it will create a new `JsonResult`([link](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Http/ApiController.cs#L463))

And this is the method which create a `HttpResponseMessage` which is a json.([link](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Http/Results/JsonResult.cs#L102))

```
public virtual Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    return Task.FromResult(Execute());
}

private HttpResponseMessage Execute()
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

    try
    {
            ArraySegment<byte> segment = Serialize();
            response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(segment.Array, segment.Offset, segment.Count);
            MediaTypeHeaderValue contentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
            contentType.CharSet = _encoding.WebName;
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = contentType;
            response.RequestMessage = _dependencies.Request;
        }
        catch
        {
            response.Dispose();
            throw;
        }

        return response;
    }
```

in `Owin` there is a `HttpMessageHandlerAdapter` class which has a `SendResponseMessageAsync` method that return `HttpResponseMessage` to client. Here's the source from github: [HttpMessageHandlerAdapter](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Http.Owin/HttpMessageHandlerAdapter.cs#L529)

```
private Task SendResponseMessageAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpResponseMessage response,
        IOwinResponse owinResponse, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        owinResponse.StatusCode = (int)response.StatusCode;
        owinResponse.ReasonPhrase = response.ReasonPhrase;

        // Copy non-content headers
        IDictionary<string, string[]> responseHeaders = owinResponse.Headers;
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<string>> header in response.Headers)
        {
            responseHeaders[header.Key] = header.Value.AsArray();
        }

        HttpContent responseContent = response.Content;
        if (responseContent == null)
        {
            SetHeadersForEmptyResponse(responseHeaders);
            return TaskHelpers.Completed();
        }
        else
        {
            // Copy content headers
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<string>> contentHeader in responseContent.Headers)
            {
                responseHeaders[contentHeader.Key] = contentHeader.Value.AsArray();
            }

            // Copy body
            return SendResponseContentAsync(request, response, owinResponse, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
```